# How to set collation for a connection in SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, locale, globalization, collation

How can i set the collation SQL Server will use for the duration of that connection?

Not until i connect to SQL Server do i know what collation i want to use.

e.g. a browser with language `fr-IT` has connected to the web-site. Any queries i run on that connection i want to follow the **French language, Italy variant** collation.

i envision a hypothetical connection level property, simlar to `SET ANSI_NULLS OFF`, but for collation<sup>1</sup>:

```
SET COLLATION_ORDER 'French_CI_AS'

SELECT TOP 100 FROM Orders
ORDER BY ProjectName
```

and later

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = 3277 
AND ProjectName LIKE '%l''ecole%'
```

and later

```
UPDATE Quotes
SET IsCompleted = 1
WHERE QuoteName = 'Cour de l''école'
```

At the same time, when a **chinese** customer connects:

```
SET COLLATION_ORDER Chinese_PRC_CI_AI_KS_WS

SELECT TOP 100 FROM Orders
ORDER BY ProjectName
```

or

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = 3277 
AND ProjectName LIKE '學校'
```

or

```
UPDATE Quotes
SET IsCompleted = 1
WHERE QuoteName = '學校的操場'
```

---

Now i **could** alter every `SELECT` statement in the system to allow me to pass in a collation:

```
SELECT TOP 100 FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = 3278
ORDER BY ProjectName COLLATE French_CI_AS
```

But you cannot pass a collation order as a parameter to a stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.GetCommonOrders 
   @CustomerID int, @CollationOrder varchar(50)
AS

SELECT TOP 100 FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = @CustomerID
ORDER BY ProjectName COLLATE @CollationOrder
```

And the `COLLATE` clause can't help me when performing an `UPDATE` or a `SELECT`.

**Note:** All string columns in the database all are already `nchar`, `nvarchar` or `ntext`. i am not talking about the default collation applied to a server, database, table, or column for non-unicode columns (i.e. `char`, `varchar`, `text`). i am talking about the collation used by SQL Server when comparing and sorting strings.

---

How can i specify per-*connection* collation?

### See also

- [Similar question, but for ADO.net and connection strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3065289/setting-collation-property-in-the-connection-string-to-sql-server-2005)
- [Similar question, but for ASP.net MVC2 and MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132530/database-connection-string-and-collation)

<sup>1</sup> hypothetical sql that exhibits locale issues

Comment: The collation is a property of the database and/or of tables/columns - it's not something you can switch dynamically for each connection...

Comment: @marc_s: It's not *entirely* a property of a database, tables, and columns. It can be a property of an `ORDER BY` as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, this question, although pertinent, has no answer. @devio is right.

Comment: In your statement you write COLLATE on a separate line after the SQL statement. This is misleading, as the COLLATE belongs to the last column of the ORDER BY clause. Remove the ORDER BY, and it will fail.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As marc_s commented, the collation is a property of a database or a column, and not of a connection.

However, you can override the collation on statement level using the [COLLATE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) keyword.

Using your examples:

```
SELECT * FROM Orders
WHERE CustomerID = 3277 
AND ProjectName COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AI_KS_WS LIKE N'學校'

UPDATE Quotes
SET IsCompleted = 1
WHERE QuoteName COLLATE Chinese_PRC_CI_AI_KS_WS = N'學校的操場'
```

Still, I cannot find a statement on using COLLATE with a dynamic collation name, leaving as only possible solution dynamic SQL and EXEC. See [this social.MSDN entry](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/transactsql/thread/f26a587d-ae3d-4bc1-84ff-0669aa7a3c8e) for an example.

Comment: i thought that collation at the server, database and table level only defined the default collation that would be applied to a column; and that collation could be changed. i thought collation on a column only affected the code page that the data was stored in if the column wasn't unicode (i.e. was char, varchar or text). i see now that collation on a column affects the physical order of indexes on that column. The `ProjectName` index has to have *some* order; that order comes from the column's collation. Arbitrary applying a different collation when performing index lookups negates any indexes