# CaseSensitivity in an user-defined function T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, user-defined-functions, casing

I have an user-defined function in T-SQL which uses CHARINDEX() internally. I take @caseSensitivity(bit) parameter as an input, which should decide the casing(collation) of the CHARINDEX() function. Is there a way to do that without making two if-constructs for every occurence of CHARINDEX()?

Comment: Can you post a code sample?

Comment: Have you considered `CASE` instead of `IF`. Depends on your logic.

Comment: @t_m, using case wont do much good either because it will produce the same quantity and quality of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, there [isn't a way to set a connection-level collation override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7210189/how-to-set-collation-for-a-connection-in-sql-server), if that is what you were thinking (I was).

However, if you are just looking for a way to be able to control this easier, then you may be able to evaluate all the CHARINDEX lookups as case-sensitive and then use [UPPER](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms180055.aspx) to make it case-insensitive when it @caseSensitive is zero:

```
DECLARE @caseSensitivity BIT = 1
DECLARE @input VARCHAR(3) = 'Abc' 
DECLARE @inputCheck VARCHAR(3) = 'B'

IF @caseSensitivity = 0
BEGIN
    SET @input = UPPER(@input)
    SET @inputCheck = UPPER(@input)
END

SELECT CHARINDEX(@inputCheck COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, @input COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS, 0)
```

Comment: This is actually a great solution for the problem. I was looking just for something like that. Thank you!