# Special characters replaced with question marks in MySql response from .net using MySqlConnection

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, ado.net

I am using MySqlConnection in my .net application to query a MySql Database from a .net application, but special characters (it is in Danish) in my resultset is shown as question marks. I have tried including "charset" (charset=utf8) in my connection string without any luck.

Comment: first check your table which character4set and collation it s using maybe it isn't utf8

Comment: Thanks very  much for your reply!
The table is set to latin1_danish_ci

Answer (score 0):

try connection with

```
Server=localhost;Port=3306;Database=xxx;Uid=x xx;Pwd=xxxx;CHARSET=latin1;
```

And then

```
partial void OnContextCreated()
{
    System.Data.Common.DbCommand command = this.Connection.CreateCommand();
    command.CommandText = "set collation_connection = utf8_slovenian_ci;";
    command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.Text;
    this.Connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

like described here [Database connection string and collation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2132530/database-connection-string-and-collation)